# Failed Docker installation attempts: Couldn't not run the the docker installtion .deb file

Tags: 22.04, docker

I am new to Linux and just installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS version. I follow the instructions on Docker website to install Docker Desktop on my Ubuntu but failed. Below is what I have done:

1. Set up Docker’s package repository.

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update

   $ sudo apt-get install \
       ca-certificates \
       curl \
       gnupg \
       lsb-release

   $ sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings

   $ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

   $ echo \
     "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
     $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
   ```
2. Download latest DEB package from the release page.
   In my case, I downloaded docker-desktop-4.10.1-amd64.deb
3. Install the package with apt as follows:

   ```
    $ sudo apt-get update

    $ sudo apt-get install ./docker-desktop-<version>-<arch>.deb
   ```

However when I ran the last command, the terminal gave an error: `E: Unsupported file ./docker-desktop-4.10.1-amd64.deb given on command line`

How to fix this problem?

Comment: I tried but this also gave the same error

Comment: I just installed Docker Engine instead and it works now. But I still want to fix this problem in case I want to install Docker Laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution. Just move the .deb installation file to Home directory and the `$sudo apt-get install ./docker-desktop-<version>-<arch>.deb` command will install Docker Desktop for you.

Comment: this answer doesn't explain what happened.  the error says it's an unsupported file but the solution was to move the file

Answer (score 0):

did you try running the install command from where the .deb file is located? Can you try that? It did the job for me.

Comment: It would give this error message: `E: Unable to locate package ./docker-desktop-4.10.1-amd64.deb` if the install command was not run from where the .deb file is located.

Comment: I did and it still gives the same error.

Comment: Did you run the command with sudo privelege? If not try that

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it fixed it:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Then the docker install worked after that:

```
sudo apt-get install ./docker-desktop-<version>-<arch>.deb
```